# Write a function named process_line that accepts a not -ve integer as input.Find no. of integers, their sum and product and Return the tuple (N,S,P)

Tags: python

Write a function named process_line that accepts a non-negative integer — i — as input. Find the following information about line-i in the file:
(1) N: number of integers in the line
(2) S: sum of all integers in the line
(3) P: product of all integers in the line
Return the tuple (N, S, P).
If i is greater than or equal to the number of lines in the file, return the tuple (-1, -1, -1). Zero-based indexing is used. So, i = 0 corresponds to the first line in the file, i = 1 the second line and i = n - 1 corresponds to the last line in a file of n lines.

This is the question, I have to write the fuction:

```
def process_line(n):
    x = open('numbers.txt','r')
    current_line=0
    N=0
    S=0
    P=1
    for lines in x:
        if current_line == n:
            for terms in lines:
                if terms!=',':
                    N=N+1
                    S=S+int(terms)
                    P=P*int(terms)
                else:
                    pass
            break
        current_line=current_line+1

    return((N,S,P))
```

Comment: Can you include contents from ```numbers.txt```

Comment: The first three lines of the file are given for your reference:
1,2,3,4,5\n
3,1,10,9,8,4,6\n
5\n

Comment: @AnushkaKrishna,  welcome to SO. Please add a question, your post is currently a statement, explain where exactly are you facing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how `numbers.txt` is laid out. You'll need something like the following (code could be shorter but this clearly shows where loops are happening):

```py
def process_line(n):
    line = None
    with open('numbers.txt') as input_file:
        for line_number, line_content in enumerate(input_file):
            if line_number == n:
                line = line_content
                break
    if line is None: return (-1, -1, -1)
    N, S, P = (0, 0, 1)
    for character in line.split(): # this line may need to change
            integer = int(character)
            N += 1
            S += integer
            P *= integer
    return (N, S, P)
```

The line with the comment currently splits a series of integers of any number of digits, separated by spaces. Passing a particular separator to that function will make it split on commas or similar if that's what you need. If the numbers are weaved throughout a line of otherwise unstructured nonsense (unlikely, but possible given we have no context), you can check if `character.isdigit()` for each character but then integers with more than one digit will need to be sorted together somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
def process_line(i):

    c,s,p=0,0,1 #this sets the variables. for products we need default to be 1
    mfile = open('numbers.txt','r')
    x = mfile.readlines()
    if len(x)>=i and i>=0:
        line = x[i]
        for i in line:
            if(i.isnumeric()):
                c+=1
                s+=int(i)
                p*=int(i)
        return (c,s,p) 
    else:
        return (-1,-1,-1)
```

c : the number of integers
s : sum of integers
p : product of integers

```
x = mfile.readlines()
if len(x)>=i and i>=0:
```

This line reads all the lines from text file and stores it as a list and the if statement checks if the value of i is less than number of lines in file and if its greater than 0(we dont need negative numbers)

```
if(i.isnumeric()):
```

this eliminates all the commas and reads only the integers.
Hope you can understand the above and rest. All the best for 1st Aug.